# contour integration with dogbone, branch cut: $\frac1{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

Compute the following integral
$$\frac1{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

Taking a branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$, satisfying $\sqrt{z^2-1}>0$ for $z>0$, I tried this problem with a 'dogbone' contour and I get,
$$\int_C\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,\mathrm{d}z=-2\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x-3}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
considering the integrations at the branch points are tends to zero as $\epsilon$ goes to zero.

After that, I got stuck because I cannot use the Cauchy integral theorem because the singularity is outside the domain. Please give an idea for this kind of problem. I feel I am wrong, and I want to know the right figure for the contour.

Comment: @MarkViola Hi Mark, I so sorry I did not see the notifications, I highly appreciate your kind effort for this question thank you very much. Yes of course this was very useful to me please do not delete the post. Please tell how do I accept the answer, is there a specific way in StackExchange?

Comment: @MarkViola I have already done it.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $R>3$, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\text{Dogbone}}\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,dz\\\\
&=\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,dz-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3},z=3\right)\\\\
&=-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3},z=\infty\right)-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3},z=3\right)
\end{align}$$

where the integral around the dog bone contour is taken counter clockwise.

The [Residue at Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity) of $f(z)=\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}$ is equal to the residue at $z=0$ of $-\frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z^2(3z-1)}$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3},z=\infty\right)&=\text{Res}\left(-\frac1{z^2}\frac{\sqrt{1/z^2-1}}{1/z-3},z=0\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{3z-1} \right)\\\\
&=-3
\end{align}$$

and the reside at $3$ is $2\sqrt 2$.

Hence, we find that

$$\oint_{\text{Dogbone}}\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,dz=2\pi i (3-2\sqrt 2)$$

where we have tacitly selected the branch of the square root on which $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is of positive sign when $z\in \mathbb{R}$, $z>1$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112962/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-viola-contour-integration-with-dogbone-branch-cut).

Comment: Dear @Mark Viola, could you please explain a little bit of step 2 to 3, why we subtract the residue at infinity?

Comment: @NuwanPriyankara Sure.  The contour $|z|=2$ does not enclose the pole at $z=3$.  The contour $|z|=R$ for $R>3$ does enclose the pole at $z=3$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand but why you subtract the residue at infinity? Why the term $2\pi i Res(f(z),z=\infty)$ is negative?

Comment: I am referring the Complex analysis Gamelin's book, and it has a topic called exterior domains in residue calculus but I failed to compare that concept with this problem

Comment: Oh, I see now.   The minus sign is required because the transformation $z\mapsto \frac1z$ reverses the orientation of the contour from counter-clockwise to clock wise.  The minus sign accounts for the reversal of orientation.

Comment: Yes that minus sign is coming from the calculation of the residue at infinity but I am looking for step 3, $\oint_{|z|=R} \frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}dz = -2\pi iRes(f(z), z=\infty)$

Comment: With the branch cut chosen from $z=-1$ to $z=1$, the function $\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}$ is holomorphic in the region $|z|>R>3$.  Hence $$\oint_{|z|=R} \frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}\,dz=-2\pi i \text{Res}\left( \frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z-3}, z=\infty\right)$$

Comment: @MarkViola Hi Mark. Sorry for that, anyway I wrote this answer to my professor but he was not happy with that but I think this was a good motivation for me to enter this path of integration. Thank you Mark

Comment: @MarkViola Still I could not get the whole idea of this question can you tell me the meaning of taking a branch of satisfying  $\sqrt{(z^2-1)}>0$ for $z>1$. You just mentioned in your answer can you tell more about it?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
*Compute* the following integral:
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\int_{\verts{z} = 2}{\root{z^{2} - 1} \over z - 3}\,
{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}}$.
I'll choose de *principal branchs* of
$\ds{\root{z \pm 1}}$. Namely,
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\root{z \pm 1}} & \ds{=} & 
\ds{\root{\verts{z \pm 1}}\expo{\ic\arg\pars{z \pm 1}}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\arg\pars{z \pm 1}} & \ds{\in} &
\ds{\pars{-\pi,\pi},\qquad z \not= \mp 1} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
The above path $\ds{\braces{z\ \mid\ \verts{z} = 2}}$ doesn't *enclose* any pole.

---

- Once the branch cuts are set in place, we have to add the contributions from paths slightly above and below the cuts.
- Once it's done, the integral is evaluated along a *closed* contour: It vanishes out.
- Of course, we have to subtract the previous adding $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{see the first}\ \bullet\ \mbox{above}~}}$.
  \begin{align}
  &\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
  \int_{\verts{z} = 2}{\root{z^{2} - 1} \over z - 3}\,
  {\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}} =
  \int_{\verts{z} = 2}
  {\root{\pars{z + 1}\pars{z - 1}} \over z - 3}\,
  {\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
  \\[5mm] = &
  \require{cancel}
  \cancel{-\int_{-2}^{-1}{\pars{\root{-x - 1}\expo{\ic\pi/2}}
  \pars{\root{1 - x}\expo{\ic\pi/2}} \over x - 3}\,
  {\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}}\label{1}\tag{1}
  \\[2mm] &
  -\int_{-1}^{1}{\root{x + 1}
  \pars{\root{1 - x}\expo{\ic\pi/2}} \over x - 3}\,
  {\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
  \\[2mm] &
  -\int_{1}^{-1}{\root{x + 1}
  \pars{\root{1 - x}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}} \over x - 3}\,
  {\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
  \\[2mm] &
  \cancel{-\int_{-1}^{-2}{\pars{\root{-x - 1}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}}
  \pars{\root{1 - x}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}} \over x - 3}\,
  {\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}}\label{2}\tag{2}
  \\[5mm] = &
  -\,{1 \over \pi}\int_{-1}^{1}
  {\root{1 - x^{2}} \over x - 3}\,\dd x =
  \bbx{3 - 2\root{2}} \approx 0.1716 \\ &
  \end{align}
  Integrals in lines (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) cancel each other. This happens because the combined branch cuts leaves a branch cut in $\ds{\bracks{-1,1}}$.

Comment: Can you explain to me a little bit I am new for the contour integrals, why all terms are negative? Why you only consider the integral only this $-2$ to $1$ to $-2$ region, why you did not consider $-2$ to $2$ to $-2$?

Comment: @NuwanPriyankara I just add some additional comments with marks $\bullet$'s.I include the pieces back and forth in $\left(-2,-1\right)$ which are not neccesary ( they cancel each other ).